# Shortest Current Longest Winning Streak in NBA history

Tags: trivia, nba

As of today (March 4) the longest current winning streak in the NBA is 3 games (3 different teams).  That seems highly unusual.  What is the all time shortest current longest winning streak (I guess the theoretical minimum is 1)?

Comment: 1, on the [1st November 1946](https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/194611010TRH.html), the first NBA game. Slightly more seriously, how are you defining winning streaks across seasons, and do playoffs count or not?

Comment: Good point.  I'll limit the answer to streaks inside one regular season only.

Comment: Inside one regular season gives you the same problem after every team's first match...

Comment: You also need to time-limit this, to after the merger I'd suggest, or more recent.

Comment: There is a pending edit to remove "any league" as the question already exists for MLB, but it also exists for the NBA alone (for a championship team in both cases). I'm still not sure what answer is possible here beyond "1 game, by every team who had a LWL occur in three consecutive matches" which is far too long to be a reasonably scoped question.